# React access redux store in axios interceptor

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I want to access redux store in axios's interceptor which configures jwt token, so I import the store into the API.js file. But it immediately logged out some errors.[image]

Here's the axios instance

```
import axios from "axios";
import { store } from '../redux/store';

export const SERVERURL = "some url";

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
const API = axios.create({ baseURL: "some url" });

API.interceptors.request.use(req => {
  // something I want to do
  return req;
});

export default API;
```

Here's the store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import userReducer from "./user";

export const store =  configureStore({ reducer: { user: userReducer } });
```

And the index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import {store} from "./redux/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I want to know what would be the problem?

Comment: it's not related, you must have some other issue with the `user` key requested. The way you imported `store` is correct.

Comment: can you share `./user` file ?

Comment: something wrong with `userReducer `

Answer (score 14):

It's a circular import dependency issue, caused by trying to directly import the `store` file into other parts of the codebase.  You'll need to avoid doing that.

Per our docs, one recommended option is to add a small `injectStore()` function to the Axios interceptors file, and inject the store into the interceptors as part of the app setup in `index.js`:

https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure#how-can-i-use-the-redux-store-in-non-component-files

```js
// common/api.js

let store

export const injectStore = _store => {
  store = _store
}

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  config.headers.authorization = store.getState().auth.token
  return config
})
```

```js
// index.js

import store from './app/store'
import { injectStore } from './common/api'
injectStore(store)
```

Answer (score 4):

I used this approach.

Create axios instance

services/index.ts

```
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from 'axios'

const instance: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
  },
})

export default instance
```

Create interceptor. Axios instance should be separated from interceptor so you can call the instance separately.

services/interceptor.ts

```
import { AxiosError, AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios'

import instance from './index'

const setUpInterceptor = (store: any) => {
  const handleError = async (error: AxiosError) => {
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }

  instance.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config: any | AxiosRequestConfig) => {
      /* your logic here */
      return config
    }
  )

  instance.interceptors.response.use((response) => response, handleError)
}

export default setUpInterceptor
```

Here, all you need to do is to initialize the interceptor in your root js file `_app.tsx`, `app.js` or `index.js` then you can do now your logic in your interceptor.ts

```
import setUpInterceptor from '@/utils/services/interceptor'
import { useStore } from 'react-redux'
const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  const store = useStore()
  setUpInterceptor(store) //<-- initialize the interceptor here

  return (
    <PersistGate persistor={store.__persistor}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </PersistGate>
  )
}
```

Source: https://www.bezkoder.com/redux-refresh-token-axios/

Answer (score 0):

My take on it was to have one export for the axios instance and one export for the setup like so:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { BASEURL } from '@env';
import { checkLoginStatus } from '../../redux/actions/auth';

export let axiosInstance = null;

export const setupAxiosInstance = (store) => {
    axiosInstance = axios.create({
        baseURL: BASEURL,
        headers: { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${store.getState().auth.userInfo.access_token}`
        },
        withCredentials: true
    });

    axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(async req => {
        store.dispatch(checkLoginStatus());
        return req;
    }, error => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    });
}
```

I used **setupAxiosInstance(store);** in my app.js file (maybe index.js for you) similar to https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure#how-can-i-use-the-redux-store-in-non-component-files. So when the application loads the store is passed to the function and thus setting up the axios instance with the interceptor.

So the flow is:

The axiosInstance is empty at first, gets instanciated by the application startup, then the user logs in, now the user can make a secured request by importing the axiosInstance itself, which will check the login status before each secured request.